# EFS for Clickhouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, clickhouse, amazon-efs

I've been looking for backup solutions and strategies for Clickhouse. All of the officially recommended methods seem to be rather archaic and slow at restore.
I was thinking of using Amazon EFS as the primary storage solution which simplifies a lot of things for my use case. However, the `lifecycle policy` and the `IA storage class` shebang makes it complicated especially the 90 day limit.

I really need some comments if anyone else has tried to use EFS  as the primary storage for any Bigdata warehouse. Hidden caveats or if it's been good.
Please assist.

Comment: There is a benchmark and caveats here: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/31113